# How to represent N as minimum number of palindrome numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, palindrome

How to represent N as minimum number of palindrome numbers?

for eg 127 = 121+6

for eg 200 = 191 + 9

Comment: Please edit to include your thoughts on the question.  Where did you encounter this problem?  Is this from a coding competition? (it certainly looks more like a coding exercise than a math problem).

Comment: @RossMillikan the smallest counter-example for the greedy algorithm is $302=111+191=292+10$.

Comment: All $N<10^6$ are expressible via sum of at most $3$ palindromes.

Comment: @lulu i myself thought of this question

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin  All $N$ can be expressed this way with at most $3$ palindromes, see [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.06208.pdf).

Comment: @sqrt  The result I mentioned in my last comment simplifies the search enormously.  See also, [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-number-of-palindromes-required-to-express-n-as-a-sum-set-2/).